# persisting array like plot/graph data in cocoa touch

Tags: cocoa-touch

I am working on a graphing application that will come with some predefined graphs and will be able to download graphs as csv from the internet when updating. The csv files are basically converted into dictionaries of arrays or some similar structure and are passed to the graphing view. What would be the best way to persist those arrays into disk ? Would using core data be a path or am I better of storing the data as plists ? If I have to go with core data I would have to create some kind of model that stores an array value and associate it with another model or something like that which seems like an overkill for this kind of task.

If I had to make a decision on my own I would go with plists. Core data seems like a very bad fit for my task but due to my cocoa noobness any opinions would be of great value.

Thanks,
Dimitris

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is more complicated and you will only feel a gain in performance when having hundreds of thousands of records.

If you plan to have only some graphs then do it with plists and in future, when you get more experience with cocoa-touch, you can always upgrade and use CoreData.
If you use CoreData from the beginning and later you decide you want to change something in the model, migrating it is PITA (I've heard).